# Word for "crawl upward"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I thought of the word "climb" but I think climbing is a vertical movement. Like, you climb a mountain, or a tree.

> I knelt down on the log and stayed like that, as though preparing to
>   do push-ups. Finally, taking a deep breath, I began to [...].

In this case, the log is bending upwards. Maybe it can still be called climbing? Or maybe there's a more appropiate word? One that means "crawling upward"?

Comment: "Shinny up", perhaps.  Though there's nothing wrong with "crawl upward".  (Note that "shinny" would imply that the log is "relatively" vertical -- maybe 45 degrees or more.  It is the motion made, more or less, by a lineman climbing a telephone pole.)

Comment: If the reader already knows your orientation then 'move forward' or a variation of that would imply climbing. Another possibility is  'ascend'.

Comment: *Crawl* seems like the obvious word*.

Comment: If you want a word connotative of exertion, you could use "claw" - "I began to claw my way up the tree" or "I clawed my way up the tree"

Comment: "I began to struggle moving upward" ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about [**'clamber'**](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/clamber):

> to ​climb up, ​across, or into ​somewhere with ​difficulty, using the ​hands and the ​feet:
>   *They clambered over/up the ​rocks.
>   I clambered into/onto the ​bus.
>   She clambered into ​bed.*  (-- Cambridge Dictionaries Online)

Answer (score 2):

The word ['scramble'](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/scramble?s=t) is often used to refer to progression upwards on a slope of uncertain stability (i.e loose stones, rocks or sand etc.), both as a verb ("I scrambled up the slippery slope") and as a noun ("We are going on a scramble this morning, to reach the summit"). Although not perhaps used specifically for crawling up inclined tree trunks, it should convey the same sense.

> **verb** (used without object), scrambled, scrambling.
>
> 1 - to climb or move quickly using one's hands and feet, as down [or up*] a rough incline.
>
> **my addition*.
>
> **noun**
>   12 - a quick climb or progression over rough, irregular ground.
>
> *www.dictionary.com*

Answer (score 1):

You could say

> "I began to inch forward."

This way, the orientation of the tree is, in a sense, irrelevant. The picture in the reader's mind is of a person moving progressively, albeit painstakingly, ahead.

Comment: Or "inch upward" would work also.